# loading shared libs has errors android

Tags: android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I built an android application which uses the libcurlstatic.a, libssl.so,and libcrypto.so in native code and generates  one more shared lib called libcurlapp.so ,, Here I would like to know that when ever I want to load this lib in my application is it necessary to load all the libraries or only libcurlapp.so will be enough ..?

Comment: Why don't you experiment a bit and find out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your Java code is responsible for loading all necessary shared libraries in the proper order.

This only involves the libs you install with your APK. The system libraries that come with the device in /system/lib will be loaded as needed by the system.

The order you load the libs is important: if libcurlapp.so makes calls to libssl.so and libcrypto.so, you should first load libssl.so and libcrypto.so.